# Material-ui Grid Responsive Direction Column Width doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid-layout

I have read the Material UI Grid List and Flexbox/FlexGrow property, which I understand, and it works correctly if I don't specify a direction. I am trying to set up a Grid with Vertical orientation. Looks like when we assign the ***align-center*** property, the width is not what we specify. Example: (style)

```
const styles = () => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },

    paper: {
        margin: '10px'
    },

    textField: {
        width: '100%',
        marginTop: '10px',
        marginLeft: '10px'
    },

    gridBorder: { 
        borderColor: 'transparent',
        borderWidth: 'thin',
        borderStyle: 'dotted',
        borderRadius: '12px'
    }
});
```

Render Method:

```
<div id='registration'>
    <Grid container spacing={4} direction='column' className={classes.root}>
        <Grid item xl={4} lg={4} xs={12}>
            <TextField required label="Email" id='' className={classes.textField}  onChange={this.handleChange}  />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xl={4} lg={4} xs={12}>
            <TextField required label="Password" id='' className={classes.textField}  onChange={this.handleChange}  />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</div>
```

It looks like this:[image: Picture]. It seems correct, but as soon as I set ***align-items*** property, it goes beyond my understanding. So when I inject the following line:

```
<Grid container spacing={4} direction='column' className={classes.root} alignItems='center'>
```

It starts looking like this:[image: middle align] I read various threads here and none of the thread talked about the direction. Can someone please help me understand this? Why the width reduces as soon as I set it to center? What I am missing?

**Update**:
I am able to fix it with a workaround. But I will really like to be able to align it to center without using this workaround. I added a fake grid before the original grid, to make it look like it is in center. The code is:

```
<Grid container direction='row'>
    <Grid item xs={1} xl={4} lg={4}>
        <Grid container direction='column' className={[classes.root, 'same-row', 'background-test'].join(' ')}>
            <Grid item>Fake Grid</Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item  xs={1} xl={4} lg={4}>
        <Grid container direction='column' className={[classes.root, 'same-row'].join(' ')}>
            <Grid item>
                <TextField required label="Email" id='' className={classes.textField}  onChange={this.handleChange}  />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
                <TextField required label="Password" id='' className={classes.textField}  onChange={this.handleChange}  />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>            
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and the result is:[image: fake grid]. But still doesn't answer my question, that why aligning to center will reduce the width.

Comment: How do you want to display it ?

Comment: Same as first screenshot, but in center. As soon as I bring it to center, it reduces the width.

Answer (score 6):

Using breakpoints is not supported for column grids:

https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#direction-column-column-reverse

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

> You can use the useMediaQuery hook :

```
const breakpoint = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("sm"));

  return (
    <Grid
      direction={breakpoint ? "column" : "row"}>
```

Comment: what is useMediaQuery? are you importing this from any specific library or dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

On the official documentation page there is no spacing={4} for grid. Enums go on 8 for the container type, so I guess there is the root of your problem.

Comment: No it's not. I tried even after deleting the spacing attribute. It is something with the GridLayout. I can definitely find workarounds, but I wanna understand why this is behaving so. It doesn't look right. It should allow me to keep the width according to the xl/xs or whatever I wanna give. Why shifting it to center will change the width?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar with what you tried. I found the following solution:

```
<Grid container md={12} direction="row">
    <Grid item md={2}/> // added this in order to offset the below Grid
    <Grid item md={8}>
        <Grid container spacing={2} direction="column">
            <Grid item>
                <FormControl fullWidth>
                    <FormLabel>Username</FormLabel>
                    <TextField id="outlined-basic" variant="standard"/>
                </FormControl>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
                <FormControl fullWidth>
                    <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                    <TextField id="outlined-basic" variant="standard" type="password"/>
                </FormControl>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
                <Button type="submit" variant="contained">LOGIN</Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And the result is:
[image]

And a screenshot with some borders to show the grid items and the margins  [image]